# Error writing tests using Mockito and async calls from Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, testing, mockito, android-testing

I'm trying to write some tests for my Android app using Mockito and I keep getting this error:

> Wanted but not invoked:
>   view.displayProfiles(
>       [com.example.reconheca.model.Profile@1e800aaa, com.example.reconheca.model.Profile@185a6e9, com.example.reconheca.model.Profile@6f03482]
>   );
>   -> at com.example.reconheca.view.ProfileListActivityPresenterTest.shouldPassProfileToView(ProfileListActivityPresenterTest.java:48)
>   Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

These are my classes been called:

ProfileListActivityPresenterTest

```
private String usedId = "string";
private ArrayList<Profile> PROFILE_LIST = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Profile(), new Profile(), new Profile()));
private Task<ArrayList<Profile>> task;
private ProfileListActivityPresenter presenter;

@Rule
public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

@Mock
ProfileFirestoreRepository profileRepository;

@Mock
ProfileListActivityView view;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    task = getTestTaskWithResult();
    presenter = new ProfileListActivityPresenter(view, profileRepository);
}

@Test
public void shouldPassProfileToView() {
    when(profileRepository.getProfilesFromUser(usedId)).thenReturn(task);
    presenter.loadProfiles(usedId);
    verify(view).displayProfiles(task.getResult());
}

@Test
public void shouldHandleNoProfile() {
    when(profileRepository.getProfilesFromUser(usedId)).thenReturn(task);
    presenter.loadProfiles(usedId);
    verify(view, never()).displayNoProfiles();
}

public Task<ArrayList<Profile>> getTestTaskWithResult() {
    TaskCompletionSource<ArrayList<Profile>> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<>();
    taskCompletionSource.setResult(PROFILE_LIST);
    return taskCompletionSource.getTask();
}
```

ProfileListActivityPresenter

```
private ProfileListActivityView view;
private ProfileFirestoreRepository profileFirestoreRepository;

public ProfileListActivityPresenter(ProfileListActivityView view, ProfileFirestoreRepository profileFirestoreRepository) {
    this.view = view;
    this.profileFirestoreRepository = profileFirestoreRepository;
}

public void loadProfiles(String userId) {
    Task<ArrayList<Profile>> task = profileFirestoreRepository.getProfilesFromUser(userId);

    task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ArrayList<Profile>>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ArrayList<Profile>> task) {
            task.addOnSuccessListener(profiles -> {
                if (profiles.isEmpty()){
                    view.displayNoProfiles();
                } else {
                    view.displayProfiles(profiles);
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(exception -> view.displayError(exception.getMessage()));
        }
    });
}
```

ProfileListActivity

```
public class ProfileListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ProfileListActivityView {

// Omitted code

@Override
public void displayProfiles(List<Profile> profileList) {
    Profile[] profiles = profileList.toArray(new Profile[0]);
    profileAdapter = new ProfileAdapter(ProfileListActivity.this, profiles);
    gridView.setAdapter(profileAdapter);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void displayNoProfiles() {
    noProfileTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

}

DatabaseProfileFirestoreRepository

```
public class DatabaseProfileFirestoreRepository implements ProfileFirestoreRepository {

private static final String TAG = "ProfileFirestoreRepo";

private final CollectionReference collectionReference;
private final String collectionName;

public DatabaseProfileFirestoreRepository(String collectionName) {
    this.collectionName = collectionName;

    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    this.collectionReference = db.collection(this.collectionName);
}

@Override
public Task<ArrayList<Profile>> getProfilesFromUser(String userId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Getting profiles...");
    return collectionReference
            .whereEqualTo(Constant.PROFILE_USER_ID, userId)
            .get()
            .continueWith(new Continuation<QuerySnapshot, ArrayList<Profile>>() {
                @Override
                public ArrayList<Profile> then(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    ArrayList<Profile> profileList = new ArrayList<>();
                    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = task.getResult();
                    assert querySnapshot != null;
                    if (querySnapshot.isEmpty()){
                        return profileList;
                    } else {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Map<String, Object> data = document.getData();

                            Profile profile = new Profile(document.getId(), (String) data.get(Constant.PROFILE_USER_ID), (String) data.get(Constant.PROFILE_NAME), (String) data.get(Constant.PROFILE_PICTURE_PATH));
                            profileList.add(profile);
                        }
                        return profileList;
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

}

The method getProfilesFromUser return a task using Cloud Firestore located at DatabaseProfileFirestoreRepository.

After the task is completed, the onSuccess send the profiles to my Activity and the Activity displays the profiles on the screen.

Using the debug mode, I see that the code never executes the task.addOnCompleteListener and forward so displayProfiles never gets called. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Obs.: The code works well, the problem is running the tests only

Comment: Hi, i'm not sure why're you sending `profiles` in ` task.addOnSuccessListener(profiles -> {` and you haven't mentioned were have you invoked `profiles`.

Comment: Hi @the_underrated, I edited the question with more information. Basically, I sending `profiles` to an activity that displays those profiles on screen.
So after the task is completed and successful, a call to `view.displayProfiles(profiles)` is made if profiles is not empty.